# Google Apps Script - Move Cursor onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to implement a Table of Contents in the sidebar of a Google Docs document which will take you to the appropriate sections when clicked. I am generating the HTML for the sidebar element by element, and I see that there is a `moveCursor(position)` function in `Document` class, but I can't see how to actually call it using onclick. Not the full code but shows the problem:

```
function generateHtml() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><body>');
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();

  //Iterate each document element
  var totalElements = body.getNumChildren();
  for(var i = 0; i < totalElements; ++i) {
    var element = body.getChild(i);

    if(element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      var text = paragraph.getText();

      if(text.trim()) { //Not blank paragraph
        var position = document.newPosition(element, 0);

        /**Would like to have <a onclick=document.moveCursor(position)> here**/

        //Show first 20 chars as preview in table of contents
        html.append('Detected paragraph ')
        .append(text.substring(0, 20))
        .append('<br />');
      }
    }
  }

  html.append('</body></html>');
  return html;
}
```

How can I accomplish this in Apps Script? The code can be completely restructured as needed.

Comment: You are trying to invoke a server side method in client code directly in one step.  You can't do that directly.  From the HTML, you need to use `google.script.run.myFunctionName();` where `myFunctionName()` is a server side function.  (In a script file = extension is .gs)  See the [google.script.run documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
/**Would like to have <a onclick=document.moveCursor(position)> here**/
```

Change to:

```
<div onmouseup="myClientFunction()">Text Here</div>
```

Add a `<script>` tag to your HTML:

```
<script>
  var valueToSend = code to get value;

  window.myClientFunction = function() {
    google.script.run
      .myGsFunctionToMoveCursor(valueToSend);
  };
</script>
```

Then you need a `myGsFunctionToMoveCursor()` function in a script file (.gs extension)

```
function myGsFunctionToMoveCursor(valueReceived) {
  //To Do - Write code to move cursor in Google Doc
  . . . Code to move cursor
};
```

Comment: I see how I would use google.script.run to call my own function now, but how could I also call it with a parameter such as position? I suppose I could create a table mapping from an id to position and then do ```onmouseup="myClientFunction(newID())"``` but that seems very roundabout. Is there a better way to associate an object with each element?

Comment: Maybe you could count the number of child elements (nodes) in the parent?  Instead of hard coding the numbers.  Maybe this is more of an HTML and DOM question at this point?